# Как вывести данные на страницу в виде матрицы (2x2, 3x3 и т.д.)

Tags: веб-программирование, html, вёрстка, django

Доброго времени суток.
Учу **django** и **html**.
Столкнулся вот с чем:
Хочу вывести данные (например новости) из БД на страницу в виде матрицы.
Во view.py делаю так:

```
def show_news(request,pageNumber=1):
    allNews = MainNews.objects.all()
    currentPage = Paginator(allNews,4)
    return render_to_response('news.html',{ 'news':currentPage.page(pageNumber) })
```

В html файле так:

```
{% block news %}
    {% for n in news %}
        <div>
            <h1><a href="/"></a></h1>
            <h4><a href="/news/get/{{ n.id }}/">{{ n.news_title|upper }}</a></h4>
            <p><a href="/news/get/{{ n.id }}/">
                  <img src="{% static "" %}{{ n.news_img }}" alt=""></a>
            </p>
            <p>{{ n.news_text|truncatewords:15 }} 
                <a href="/news/get/{{ n.id }}/">читать</a></p>
            <label>Дата: {{ n.news_date }}</label>
            <label>Категория: Пусто</label>
            <hr>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Все выводится вертикально конечно же.
Как сделать чтобы было два или три дива на одной строке и на следующих.
Или как правильно делать такой вывод?(используя шаблоны django или же js?) 
Помогите пожалуйста!

PS. И еще позвольте, простите мою дерзость и незнание, спросить. Как выводить новости из базы, чтобы Первая новость на странице была последней добавленной в базу?

Comment: только через order_by

Comment: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однако что-то получилось как я хотел.
Для упрощения верстки поставил foundation framework.

Есть такой замечательный шаблон `{% cylce %}` с помощью него получилось расположить дивы как нужно:

[image: Imgur]

А вывести новости в обратном порядке `MainNews.objects.all().order_by('-id')`

Если это можно сделать по-другому и интересней, посоветуйте, пожалуйста ;)

Comment: Можно метод all() убрать. Больше я бы ничего делать не стал. В Managers такой запрос переносить явно не стоит.

Comment: Спасибо! А расскажите, если не затруднит, что значит переносить в Managers?

Comment: Про менеджеры все в документации подробно расписано, как впрочем многие другие вещи.
http://djbook.ru/rel1.4/topics/db/managers.html
Советую еще почитать Daniel Greenfeld - Two Scoops of Django. Если есть хоть какое-то представление о django, книга будет полезна.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри как сделано у меня [github.com](https://github.com/alexandr-nino/demo_ehop/blob/master/apps/ecommerce/templates/ecommerce/category_detail.html#L21). Возможно, и даже вероятнее всего, у тебя логика разметки будет отличаться, но смысл в целом останется одинаковый.

Comment: Спасибо! Интересно в принципе поучится на примере вашего кода )